# Is there a way to listen to when a transaction is created?

Tags: gnosis-safe

When a transaction is posted to the safe-transaction-api hosted by Gnosis, is there a way I can listen for new transactions for a specific safe? Are there webhooks? I want to be able to ping my multi-sig owners to sign!

Answer (score 0):

We currently do not provide this functionality. The mobile apps for the Gnosis Safe will receive push notifications for different actions related to the Safes managed in the app. If you add an owner key this also includes the creation of new transactions.